# Hibernate many to one of the same entity. How to delete?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have Type class as entity.  The Type can have one parent type and many children types.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "type")
public class Type extends EntityItem {

...
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_type", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Type parentType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent_type")
    private List<Type> childTypes = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```

When I create parent type with children and save them, all is OK. But when I'm trying to delete the parent, I have the error below

```
2018-08-05 15:58:50,843 INFO  [main] impl.TypeServiceImpl (TypeServiceImpl.java:53) - Type delete: Type [id=1000, parentType=null]
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        type 
    where
        id=?
Aug 05, 2018 3:58:50 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
Aug 05, 2018 3:58:50 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: update or delete on table "type" violates foreign key constraint "fk_gbqg39jytwquch0bjm9j80gsf" on table "type"
  Подробности: Key (id)=(1000) is still referenced from table "type".
```

Could you please explain what is wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes you cant delete "parentType" because there is a reference to that record. If you want to delete parent then you have to delete its all the child types first. You can add "cascade = CascadeType.ALL" to OneToMany relationship then it will automatically delete the child types

Comment: @Keaz Thank you for the answer. Is there a way in hibernate to delete references? Or I need to delete it manually.

Comment: Just put the "cascade = CascadeType.ALL" in @OneToMany annotation.

Comment: @Keaz It didn't help

Comment: Ok, try adding this @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: Remove all children manually beforehand

Comment: @Keaz It also didn't help. Error is the same.

Comment: How do you delete the object. Can you share the code.

Comment: @Keaz public void delete(ID id) {
  entityManager.createQuery(String.format("DELETE FROM %s e WHERE e.id = :id", entityClass.getSimpleName())).setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
 }

Comment: @Dron4K why dont you use hibernate session to delete object?